# In Labyrinth do goblins reproduce by transforming unwanted people?

Tags: labyrinth

In the 1986 film *[Labyrinth](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0091369/)* 16-year old Sarah wishes away her baby half-brother, Toby, to the goblins of the eponymously titled *Labyrinth* book she had been reciting from.

Answering her wish is the Goblin King, Jareth who absconds with the child. After Sarah reneges on her wish, Jareth reluctantly gives Sarah 13 hours to solve his labyrinth and find Toby before he is turned into a goblin forever.

Is this how the goblins of Labyrinth reproduce, by transforming unwanted humans into goblins?

Comment: Possible dupe of [How did Jareth become the Goblin King?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/221890/20774), specifically my answer which references the novelisation "*It pleased him to think of his Labyrinth as a board game; if you got too close to the winning square, you might find a snake taking you back to the start. No one had, and very few had gotten as far as this disturbing girl, who was too old to be turned into a goblin. Jareth examined her face in his crystal. Too old to be a goblin, but too young to be kept by him, damn her innocent eyes."*

Comment: I think that’s different question but the _other_ cited novelization passage of your answer suggests the answer: “_when many babies had been offered to him…_”. It seems like this is the way goblins have always been “minted”: specifically human children.

Comment: That passage is referring more to his search for an heir rather than more goblins to add to his horde

Comment: I'm not sure reproduce is exactly what you mean? Are you asking if this is there only way of increasing the population? If so, consider making the title *In Labyrinth does the goblin population only increase by transforming people?* in an [edit], and similar changes in the body

Comment: @AncientSwordRage No, not being aware of the further confirmation from the novelization at time of my question, I wanted to know “In Labyrinth, do goblins reproduce by transforming unwanted people,” an extrapolation of the singular conflict covered by the film’s relationship between Sarah, Toby and the Goblin King.

Comment: Ok, but reproduce means to create new offspring via some action of the 'parents' (for lack of a better word). Whereas transforming is going from state to another. Toby already exists, so any transformation couldn't be called 'reproduction'. Perhaps you mean to ask, is 'transforming unwanted people, part of the process of goblin reproduction'? Otherwise I can't see how to clearly understand your question

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Exactly. Reproduction is a fundamental feature of all known life, including in context of the fantasy of this exchange, Labyrinth’s goblins. My question was consequently, “in Labyrinth, do goblins reproduce by transforming unwanted people?”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The labyrinth prequal comic book shows a previous goblin king taking a child in order to drain their time, in order to extend his own life through the use of a mechanical device.

The comic book implies that this is unusual, and that the taking of children by goblins in this manner wasn't the norm.

The goblin king of the prequal has a biological son, so presumably he reproduced through traditional means, though from memory no mother is specifically mentioned.

Some characters mention familiar relationships, though it wasn't made clear if they were goblins as no definition of a goblin was provided, and there appeared to be significant variations between goblins.

Traditions were mentioned involving the naming of children, and children as having parents, and against suggesting that they were born rather created.

Comment: It was epiphany from novelization reference and comment that Goblin Kings aren’t actually even goblins. I suppose the geriatric practices of aging non-goblin Goblin Kings is a whole separate can of worms from asexual methods goblins use to continue the species.

Comment: The comic implies that Jareth was the one and only example of a non-goblin being the king of the Goblins. It's probably safer to say that he was human, but that he is now part Goblin as he is an amalgam of a human child and the Owl King.